# Barring 1784, when has UK Parliament's legal sovereignty over-ridden the electorate's political sovereignty?

Tags: united-kingdom

*An Introduction to the Study of the Law of the Constitution* was first published in 1885, but I quote the 1915 8 edn.  [p. 250 of this transcribed online PDF](http://oll-resources.s3.amazonaws.com/titles/1714/Dicey_0125_EBk_v6.0.pdf). Here's [scan of original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrcge.jpg).

Barring [Pitt in 1784](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/59229) quoted below, when else did UK Parliament's legal sovereignty trample and overpowere the electorate's political sovereignty?

> The true answer to the objection thus raised appears to be that the observance of the
>   main and the most essential of all constitutional rules, the rule, that is to say, requiring
>   the annual meeting of Parliament, is ensured, without any necessity for Parliamentary
>   action, by the temporary character of the Mutiny Act, and that the power of
>   Parliament to compel obedience to its wishes by refusing to pass the Act is so
>   complete that the mere existence of the power has made its use unnecessary. In matter
>   of fact, no Ministry has since the Revolution of 1689 ever defied the House of
>   Commons, unless the Cabinet could confide in the support of the country, or, in other
>   words, could count on the election of a House which would support the policy of the
>   government. To this we must add, that in the rare instances in which a Minister has
>   defied the House, the refusal to pass the Mutiny Act has been threatened or
>   contemplated. Pitt's victory over the Coalition is constantly cited as a proof that
>   Parliament cannot refuse to grant supplies or to pass an Act necessary for the
>   discipline of the army. Yet any one who studies with care the great “Case of the
>   Coalition” will see that it does not support the dogma for which it is quoted. Fox and
>   his friends did threaten and did intend to press to the very utmost all the legal powers
>   of the House of Commons. They failed to carry out their intention solely because they
>   at last perceived that the majority of the House did not represent the will of the
>   country. What the “leading case” shows is, that the Cabinet, when supported by the
>   Crown, and therefore possessing the power of dissolution, can defy the will of a
>   House of Commons if the House is not supported by the electors. Here we come
>   round to the fundamental dogma of modem constitutionalism; **the legal sovereignty of
>   Parliament is subordinate to the political sovereignty of the nation**. This the
>   conclusion in reality established by the events of 1784. Pitt overrode the customs,
>   because he adhered to the principles, of the constitution. He broke through the
>   received constitutional understandings without damage to his power or reputation; he
>   might in all probability have in case of necessity broken the law itself with impunity.
>   For had the Coalition pressed their legal rights to an extreme length, the new
>   Parliament of 1784 would in all likelihood have passed an Act of Indemnity for

p. 261

> illegalities necessitated, or excused, by the attempt of an unpopular faction to drive
>   from power a Minister supported by the Crown, by the Peers, and by the nation.
>   However this may be, the celebrated conflict between Pitt and Fox lends no
>   countenance to the idea that a House of Commons supported by the country would not
>   enforce the morality of the constitution by placing before any Minister who defied its
>   precepts the alternative of resignation or revolution.

These quotes below can serve as context. p. 260.

> How, it may
>   be said, is the “point” to be fixed at which, in case of a conflict between the two
>   Houses, the Lords must give way, or the Crown ought to use its prerogative in the
>   creation of new Peers? The question is worth raising, because the answer throws great
>   light upon the nature and aim of the articles which make up our conventional code.
>   This reply is, that the point at which the Lords must yield or the Crown intervene is
>   properly determined by anything which conclusively shows that the House of
>   Commons represents on the matter in dispute the deliberate decision of the nation. The truth of this reply will 
>   hardly be questioned, but to admit that the deliberate 
>   decision of the electorate is decisive, is in fact to 
>   concede that the understandings as to the action of 
>   the House of Lords and of the Crown are, what we 
>   have found them to be, **rules meant to ensure the 
>   ultimate supremacy of the true political sovereign, or, 
>   in other words, of the electoral body.**<sup>1</sup>
>         By far the most striking example of the real sense 
>   attaching to a whole mass of constitutional conven-tions is found in a particular instance, which appears 
>   at first sight to present a marked exception to 
>   the general principles of constitutional morality.  A
>   Ministry placed in a minority by a vote of the Commons have, in accordance with
>   received doctrines, a right to demand a dissolution of Parliament.
>
> <sup>1</sup>  Cf. Bagehot, *English Constitution* (1872 ed.), pp. 25-27.

pp. 264-265

> The
>   personal influence of the Crown exists, not because acts of State are done formally in
>   the Crown's name, but because neither the legal sovereign power, namely Parliament,
>   nor the political sovereign, namely the nation, wishes that the reigning monarch
>   should be without personal weight in the government of the country.

Comment: This sort of falls into the category of **'Politicians quite often make promises which they don't keep'**. Informed electorates are *quite* aware of this and factor it into their voting. You've asked a series of questions around this quote or related to it. What's really bothering you?

Comment: @simonatrcl How's "the legal sovereignty of Parliament is subordinate to the political sovereignty of the nation" related to "Politicians quite often make promises which they don't keep"?

Comment: In all those words, you have one question mark. My comment refers to that question; it was not an answer but a comment, and a question for you.

Comment: What happened with "Pitt in 1784"?

Comment: @hkBst I added a link to my post.